# Django ForeignKey Instance vs Raw ID

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to not have to pass in a model instance for a foreign key when create a new model?  Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
         db_table = u'foo'

class Bar(models.Model):
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo')

    class Meta:
         db_table = u'bar'
```

The later a post request comes in to a view - I know the the id of a foo record and just want to insert a record into the bar table.

if I do:

```
new_bar = Bar(info="something important", foo=foo_id)
new_bar.save()
```

I get a ValueError saying "Cannot assign "546456487466L": "Bar.foo" just be a "Foo" instance.

So, I get it...  it wants me to have an actual instance of the Foo model.  I understand that I can just do a get on Foo and then pass it in.  But, there seems like there must be a way to override this functionality.  I have done some googling and reading the docs, and raw_id_fields in admin seems to be the basic idea.  (which is to say, allow a raw id here).  But, don't see this option on the ForeignKey field.

It seems very inefficient to have to make a round trip to the database to get an object to get the id (which I already have).  I understand that doing the round trip validates that the id exists in the database.  But, hey...  that's why I'm using a RDBMS and have foreign keys in the first place.

Thanks

Comment: Great, classic SO-ish question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
new_bar = Bar(info="something important", foo_id=12345)
new_bar.save()
```

You can also get [foreign key values directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly). Some kind of optimization.

Comment: This worked... I still had problems until I figured something out. going to add 1 little note here and edit the answer above.  In my example above, I actually was over simplify a bit.  In the REAL models, "foo" the primary key of the table was not "id".  And the foreign was not "foo_id".  But, you STILL need to use the fieldname+"_id" to get it to work.

Comment: Isn't this strange that its not a double underscore, since id is a field of Foo.  You use a double underscore in querysets at least.

Comment: @radtek that is because you are not using Foo's id field, you are using Bar's foo_id field. If you use some sort of database client you will see that `appname_foo` has a column `id` and `appname_bar` has a column `foo_id`. I mean otherwise how would you know which Foo goes to each Bar? So in this case even in querysets you would NOT (and should NOT) use a double underscore when dealing with id's, (you avoid a join that way).