# scrapy djangoitem with Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, scrapy

This question was asked here [Foreign Keys on Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017331/foreign-keys-on-scrapy) without an accepted answer, so I am here to re-raise the question with a clearer defined minimum set up:

The django model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.Category', null=True, blank=True)
```

Note how `category` is defined is irrelevant here, but it does use `ForeignKey`. So, in django shell, this would work:

```
c = Article(title="foo", content="bar", category_id=2)
c.save()
```

The scrapy item:

```
class BotsItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Article
```

The scrapy pipeline:

```
class BotsPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['category_id'] = 2
        item.save()
        return item
```

With the above code, scrapy complains:

```
exceptions.KeyError: 'BotsItem does not support field: category_id'
```

Fair, since `category_id` is not appeared in django model, from which we get the scrapy item. For the record, if we have the pipeline (assume we have a category `foo`):

```
class BotsPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['category'] = 'foo'
        item.save()
        return item
```

Now scrapy complains:

```
exceptions.TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple
 of classes and types
```

So exactly what should we do?

Answer (score 9):

Okay I managed to solve this problem and I am putting here for the records. As hinted by the last `exceptions.TypeError`, `item['category']` expects an instance of `Category` class, in my case I am using [`django-categories`](https://github.com/callowayproject/django-categories) so in the pipeline just replace with this (assume `Category` is populated in ORM already):

```
class BotsPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['category'] = Category.objects.get(id=2)
        item.save()
        return item
```

Comment: at least, you can try ;)